# Share Access 2016 Data Over the Internet

Tags: database, azure, ms-access

We have an Access 2016 database with lots of tables, forms and reports from a client.  The client would like other people to access the data in this database but doesn't want to spend the money to convert the forms and reports to a website.  They would rather have Access 2016 as a frontend with it's forms and reports and store the data in a centralized location.  The issue is the users who will access this data won't be on the same LAN or network.

The solution I came up with was to use SQL Azure as the database backend and keep the forms and reports in the Access 2016 database frontend.  Can anyone think of an alternative?  Does Microsoft have some kind of online hosting with Office 365?  I have nothing at all against SQL Server and use it frequently but just don't want to go through the effort of upsizing the database when a simpler solution existed.

Comment: How many concurrent remote users? A Remote Desktop server (or even a spare workstation or two set up for RDP) will give you a solution that requires no changes to the actual database.

Beyond that I have had limited success with just setting up a VPN for remote users but it is SLOW.

Comment: How do you plan to secure this over the internet? This sounds like a terrible idea to me.... Creating a simple data-driven website (with the capabilities of just an access front-end) is trivial nowadays using some frameworks, I would just get on with it

Comment: We would give each user a different SQL login.There are several Access forms and reports in the database.  I agree the ideal solution is to create a website, but the client doesn't want to spend the money to convert all those forms and reports into web pages.

Comment: I used Access + Mysql (without SSL odbc connection) and it worked perfectly. Although, I would say you need a decent internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly place the back end on SQL Azure. However given that a typical internet connection is about 100 times slower, then MUCH effort is required to optimize the application. So you need significant experience on how to optimize an Access application to work with SQL server. This setup is thus doable, but will take significant amounts of work to achieve decent performance.

Another possible solution is to use a SharePoint or office 365 back end (which supports SharePoint tables). This setup only works well if table’s sizes are in general below 5000 records. You also have to ensure all table relations are standard auto number PK and child tables use a standard long number column to relate back to the parent table.

Likely the best solution is to setup a server and run remote desktop. This gives the best performance, and the end users don’t need to install access nor your front end part.

I explain in detail the “slowness” with using SQL server over the internet in this article of mine along with some suggestions and possible solutions.

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html